# MongoDB/Mongoose not saving nested properties

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

So I think I am doing something stupid, because I can't for the life of me get the following schema to work properly:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema 
  notifications:
    discussion:
        created:
            mobile: 
                stuff: 
                    hey: 
                        type: Boolean
                        default: false
            osx:  
                type: Boolean
                default: false
            web:  
                type: Boolean
                default: true
            email:  
                type: Boolean
                default: true
            sms:  
                type: Boolean
                default: false
```

All looks normal, right? Just declaring some nested properties, their types, and their defaults? Nope.

```
Information.db.User.find {}, "notifications userSettings", (err, users) ->
    for user in users
        console.log user.notifications.discussion.created
            // prints { mobile: { stuff: {} } }
```

All defaults gone, and the actual data I want to store is no where. Any ideas???

Edited to include the code for retrieving the user. Information.db.User is a refernce to the Mongoose Schema, skipping over my caching layer. The user already exists in the db, and I am trying to add the notifications object instead of having those settings stored as stringified JSON.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that creates and populates `user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have old user objects in your database that were created before you added the defaults or maybe they were left over from another project.

When I implemented your code in my test project I used an old database which already had existing users in it and got the same output as you did. I guess mongoose tries to force the schema on these user objects but it will only output the nested fields and none of the boolean fields since they are null.

When I created a new object with your schema it worked fine and I got values for all the default. Please let me know if this might have been the issue for you too.

Comment: That is the way my schema is, but in the past defaults have been assigned to objects that did not already have them. I guess i'll have to try to do a migrate to add it all then. Even so, I cant even get it to set the full object doing {$set:{notifications:newNotifications}}

Comment: Yes, you probably need to some dba:ing unfortunately. The update with that $set should defiantly work. Make sure you have the right structure of newNotifcations.

Comment: uuuuuhrg okay. hindsite is 20/20. wish i had designed this properly form the get-go.

Comment: Haha, that is always the issue :P please mark this as the accepted answer if you thought it helped :)

Comment: To expand, I solved this (officially) by settings every users nested object to the default, and THEN by performing the update with the old settings.